# Edit HTML signature in Mail 16.0 on MacOS Monterey 12.4

Tags: macos, mail.app, html, signature

Since a few day, my HTML signature are gone on *Mail*. I used to edit manually the `*.mailsignature` files located in the `~/Library/Mail/V9/MailData/Signatures/` folder and locking them to prevent *Mail* to override them.

Unfortunately, since the last update, I can't select it with the combo box:

[image]

Note that I can't select a signature created manually either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the `*.mailsignature` is clearly the wrong way to go.

I fixed my HTML signature by unchecking the *Always match my default message font* checkbox:

[image]

Copy/pasting from HTML works fine even if the preview doesn't show correctly the image. They will be rendered correctly when composing your next email with the newly created signature.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add the signature in the format with the rendered HTML. This video shows how to use a third party authoring service to copy / paste it into macOS mail app

- https://youtu.be/ZYPEWc8aoew

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Wouldn't the issues listed in the question preclude the OP from following the guide you selected?